# Когда в RAD Studio появится компиляция Delphi-приложений под Linux?

Tags: linux, delphi

Вроде еще в 2017 году было заявлено о поддержке Linux:
https://delphiaball.co.uk/2017/03/22/rad-studio-10-2-available-today-linux-delphi/

Но на сайте www.embarcadero.com до сих пор не удается найти никаких пакетов, где бы была доступна эта функциональность.

Может, кто чего знает?

Comment: Ладно, а вот если у меня сейчас 10.2 - есть ли какой пакет обновлений, сервис пак, чтобы проапгрейдиться до 10.3.2 ?

Comment: Вот тут не подскажу. Вроде минорная версия поменялась, но я бы отдельно установил 10.3.2 в новую папку.

Answer (score 1):

Поддержка сборки консольных приложений для Linux появилась в  [10.2 Tokyo](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/What%27s_New#Delphi_Linux_Compiler)

И только что вышла версия с поддержкой сборки GUI-приложений под Linux: [10.3_Rio_-_Release_2](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/10.3_Rio_-_Release_2)

Рекоммендую также вот эту тему, тут все фичи по версиям: [List of Delphi language features and version in which they were introduced/deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8460037/list-of-delphi-language-features-and-version-in-which-they-were-introduced-depre)

Comment: Стоит заметить, что поддержка линукса есть только в Enterprise и Architect редакциях Delphi, а в Professional и тем более Community - нету: [Product Editions](https://www.embarcadero.com/products/delphi/product-editions)

Answer (score 1):

Да, вроде поддержка OS Linux есть с версии 10.3.1 - вот официальный гайд, как настроить IDE и Linux для совместной работы: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/FireMonkey_for_Linux. Так же по этой ссылке можно посмотреть все поддерживаемые платформы: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Supported_Target_Platforms